# Resize an image filesize with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, imagemagick, paperclip, image-manipulation

I upload images to the server with paperclip. I scale medium images with the following code:

```
:medium => "280x100>"
```

But Also I need to fit the original image filesize to 1Mb.
Is there any way to do this with the paperclip functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such ability at the moment, but you can add validation for file size as described there https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations , so it will look like this:

```
validates_attachment :avatar, :size => { :less_than => 1.megabytes }
```

Comment: I've already added the validation but probably you're right. Maybe if needed iterative resize and check the filesize can help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how change image size in file size but you can resize original image:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :resize

  def resize
    self.image = self.image.resize "1024x1024"
  end
end
```

Comment: I also thought about smth like this but with check the original filesize before. And resize the image if it is more than 1 Mb